# array to json issue using AJAX in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with convert array to JSON in laravel using ajax request. Here is my code

AJAX code:

```
  data = {
    clients: clients,
   _token:$('input[name="_token"]').val()
  }

$.ajax({
        url: '{{URL::to('/url')}}'+'/' + trainer_id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
        }, error: function (response) {
        }
       });
```

clients is an array and it has ids. It look like: clients:
Array[3]
0:859
1:883
2:885

Laravel controller code:

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
        dd(json_encode($request->clients));
}
```

Response of code is :   "["859","883","885"]".

But I want this : ["859","883","885"].

Does anyone knows the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like `$request->clients` is already JSON.

Comment: No, it's an array  It seems like this: array:3 [
  0 => "859"
  1 => "883"
  2 => "885"
]

Comment: I have added an answer that should work. :)

Comment: json_encode-ing an array, would not result in quotes around the string. But json_encode-ing that string, would. So somewhere, it looks like it's getting double encoded.

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
      return response()->json($request->clients);
}
```

you can also send extra parms

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
      return response()->json(['data'=>$request->clients,'status'=>true]);
}
```

Comment: It returns an array and I want it in json

Answer (score 0):

The `json_encode()` returns string. Just use `dd($request->clients);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
    dd(json_encode($request->clients));  // There is no use of dd(), dd() is used for debugging purpose
}
```

change it to:

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->clients);  // We have to return this data as json that's why we use json() here
}
```

**Edit:** For sending some more data, create an array and pass `$request->clients` on its one of key and return that array like:

```
return response()->json($your_array);
```

Comment: Yeah I can do like this but I want to pass clients in one json so I can't do like this

Comment: I am not getting you ?

Comment: This is not my last response to send. I need to pass also other data in response and I am using guzzle so I am passing it like this: $requestOptions = ['form_params' => [
        "trainer_id"=> $param,
         "client_ids" => $clientArr
        ]];  . So, how can I use response()->json() with it??

Answer (score 0):

in javascript success callback

```
JSON.parse("["859","883","885"]") = [859,883,885];

JSON.parse(response); // in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function myCode($id, Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->clients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is the description](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php)   use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

```
  json_encode($request->clients, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```